# Having issues with this Mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

Hello i'm learning sql and i have some issues with joins(which i have problems understanding them)

I have this issue

> #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'tbl_respuestas'

what the query supposed to do, is count how many people(general,ignore user) has answer 'x', in 'y' question of 'z' survey

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_respuestas
INNER JOIN tbl_encuesta_usuario ON tbl_encuesta_usuario.user_id = user.id
INNER JOIN tbl_encuesta ON tbl_encuesta.id = tbl_encuesta_usuario.tbl_encuesta_id
INNER JOIN tbl_encuesta_has_tbl_preguntas ON tbl_encuesta_has_tbl_preguntas.tbl_encuesta_id = tbl_encuesta.id
INNER JOIN tbl_preguntas ON tbl_preguntas.id = tbl_encuesta_has_tbl_preguntas.tbl_preguntas_id
INNER JOIN tbl_preguntas_has_tbl_respuestas ON tbl_preguntas_has_tbl_respuestas.tbl_preguntas_id = tbl_preguntas.id
INNER JOIN tbl_respuestas ON tbl_respuestas.id = tbl_preguntas_has_tbl_respuestas.tbl_respuestas_id 
WHERE tbl_respuestas.respuesta = 2
```

Comment: can you provide sqlfiddle?

Comment: Use an alias on each of the tables then use it in the column references.

Answer (score 2):

line `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_respuestas`
and line `INNER JOIN tbl_respuestas`
does not makes sense, hence the error.
Unless it is what you want then you need to give then different name/alias like below:

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_respuestas r`

`INNER JOIN tbl_respuestas r2`

Also as a quick note you can rewrite the entire sql like below. 
It is good practice to give your tables a name for shorter referencing and makes the sql look a little cleaner.
Also if both tables you are trying to join has the same column name then you can use the keyword `USING` instead of having to write that long line `tbl_encuesta_usuario.user_id = user.id`

Please be sure to put r and r2 in its prope place

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_respuestas r
    INNER JOIN tbl_encuesta_usuario u USING user_id
    INNER JOIN tbl_encuesta e ON e.id = u.tbl_encuesta_id
    INNER JOIN tbl_encuesta_has_tbl_preguntas hp ON hp.tbl_encuesta_id = e.id
    INNER JOIN tbl_preguntas p ON p.id = hp.tbl_preguntas_id
    INNER JOIN tbl_preguntas_has_tbl_respuestas hr ON hr.tbl_preguntas_id = p.id
    INNER JOIN tbl_respuestas r2 ON r2.id = hr.tbl_respuestas_id 
WHERE r.respuesta = 2
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer and sorry for writing you late. It didn't work, using "using (user id) so i tried tbl_encuesta_usuario u using u.user_id and it didn't work also

Comment: By the way, in case i don't want to use users(i just want a general count) How it will be the query?

Comment: Oh sorry dont put parenthesis around it., use `INNER JOIN tbl_encuesta_usuario u USING (user_id)` I will update the answer...

Comment: And as for your other question, it is already counting general. Unless there are answers for non users as well. If this is so then you just need `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_respuestas` to select all the answers in that table.

Comment: No problem :) anytime